# How to query an index based on a search term and boost the results by a field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to figure out a solution for the following scenario.

User enters a search term (say iPhone). A query to fetch the aggregations on categories is executed ordered by count desc. This is to know how many products each category has for the given search term. Once I get this, I need to execute the actual search query for 'iphone' to get the list of matching products but I also need to boost the category values received in my earlier aggregation query.

e.g. 
1st aggregation query

```
GET /product/_search
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "iphone",
      "fields" : [
        "identity.name"
      ],
      "operator" : "and",
      "type": "most_fields"
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "description.categoryName.keyword" ,
        "size": 3
     }
   }
  }
}
```

RESPONSE

```
"aggregations": {
"categories": {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count": 43,
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "iPhones",
      "doc_count": 55
    },
    {
      "key": "iPhone 6 &amp; 6S Cases &amp; Screen Protectors",
      "doc_count": 38
    },
    {
      "key": "iPhone 7 Cases &amp; Screen Protectors",
      "doc_count": 38
    }
  ]
}
}
```

So now my 2nd query for getting products matching 'iphone' should have the highest boost/weight for category=iPhones followed by category=iPhone 6 & 6S Cases & Screen Protectors and then category=iPhone 7 Cases & Screen Protectors and then the rest of the results

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Top hits aggregation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Your current terms aggregation will get you the relevant categories and doc counts. Then you would use the top hits aggregation as a sub-agg to that and it will give you matching hits for your query sorted by score(default), within your categorical buckets.

Comment: Gr8. That kinda worked. This is returning top hits for the top level category aggregation. However, if the top level categories aggregation returns, say 20 categories, and I am only concerned with boosting the results by first three categories is there any other way to achieve this other than increasing the size of the top level aggregation to a high number like say 99?.

Comment: Aggregations don't actually score anything. Your top level categories aggregation is just bucketing relevant documents based on your search query so there is no way to "boost" certain buckets. Boosting only exists in the context of a search where you can boost the value of a hit on specific fields.